# Uploading multiple images in SilverStripe 3.0

Tags: php, file-upload, silverstripe

I'm using SilverStripe 3.0 and I need some help around here. I have a many to one relation between pages and images (I'm creating an image gallery). The images are uploaded into the right folder, but the CMS seems to save the wrong path for them. I'll explain a little more detailed:

I load the image in the uploader, it shows me a thumbnail while uploading. But when it finishes the upload the thumbnail disappears.

When I click the Edit button I see that it's looking for the image in the /assets folder (like /assets/picture.jpg), but it was uploaded to /assets/Uploads.

I tried setting a different upload folder using $FileField->setFolderName(), but it always looks for the images in /assets besides it uploads them in the right folder.

Any suggestion?

Comment: did you try with the latest version (3.0.2)? also, there is a bulk upload module you could use: https://github.com/colymba/GridFieldBulkEditingTools

Comment: I was busy and didn't have time to check this. Thanks for your reply, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

This was a [known bug](http://open.silverstripe.org/ticket/8006) that should be fixed with the 3.0.4/3.0.5 release.